# php version in htaccess is resetting

Tags: php, .htaccess, server, cpanel

i set my directory php version to 8 in cpanel in htaccess:

```
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php80 .php .php8 .phtml
</IfModule>
```

but it is reset to :

```
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php74 .php .php7 .phtml
</IfModule>
```

after a moment... why?

I tried changing php version to 8 and that's reset to 7 after a moment

Comment: From the information you've provided with your question it is hard to actually say why, without guessing the most viable answer seems to be that this is related to the configuration of the system you have placed the files, but as we can't see it, such kind of answer is likely not helpful. Consider to add more concrete references why you think it should work and show how you checked that those apply. If you use CPanel, IIRC use CPanel as well to set the PHP version, otherwise you might see what happens here that CPanel is resetting the PHP version to the CPanel configured one. Don't fight it.

Comment: "i set my directory php version to 8 **in cpanel** in htaccess:" - did you actually change this setting in cPanel? In which case there should also be some comment markers in `.htaccess` that cPanel adds. Or are you referring to your hosting as cpanel (as is erroneously common for some reason)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just go to CPanel's `Multi PHP Manager` page and change php version to your desired version